# Passing props to svelte component from laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, svelte

I started learning `svelte` today and I have a problem. Is it possible to pass `props/data` to a `svelte` component through `laravel blade`?

For example this is how you pass it in `vuejs`:

```
<blog-post post-title="hello!"></blog-post>
```

I don't understand from where my `svelte` component gets the data beside from `ajax`.

I'm talking here about passing data outside an .svelte component. Not passing from 1 to another .svelte file component. İm asking if you can pass data from an .php file to an component.

Comment: Try `<blog-post title="hello!"></blog-post>` I don't think props can be hyphenated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing props down in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722539/passing-props-down-in-svelte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From laravel >= 5.x (and maybe some previous versions too) there is a blade directive (in the previous ones just use `{!! json_encode($data) !!}`), just create a js variable in the php page:

```
<script>
    var data = @json($data);
</script>
```

Usually you have a glue code like the following (where you can add the element's `props`):

```
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: data.name
    }
});

export default app;
```